# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-2+3-...+(-1)^{n-1} n}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus

First I thought about proving that series doesn't converge by evaluating its limit but although I didn't manage to evaluate the limit, it intuitively seems that its limit is zero.

Since the series isn't non negative I think I can't use limit and integral criterion.

Also dirichlet and leibniz criterions seem unlikely to be of any use.

Maybe majorant criterion could be useful but I don't have any clue to what to compare sum in the numerator.

I also tried using d'alambert criterion ( I think you call it ratio test) hoping to get limit bigger than 1 but again didn't manage to evaluate the limit.

Any hints?

Comment: Can you find a closed form for $1 - 2 + 3 - \ldots + (-1)^{n - 1} n$?

Comment: What do you mean by closed form?

Comment: $f:\ n\mapsto f(n)$

Comment: Its limit is not $0$.  It is worth working out the first few values of $\frac{1-2+3-...+(-1)^{n-1} n}{n^2}$ at which point the suitable test for convergence should be obvious

Comment: Never mind, found definition online.I guess I could try that

Comment: @Henry The limit of the individual terms in the series is $0$.

Comment: @5xum: Yes, but for small $n$ the individual terms are not $0$

Comment: @Henry Did anyone say that for small $n$, the individual terms are $0$? I am only stating that the *limit* is $0$, which is in reply to you saying "its limit is not $0$" (which is just a false statement if you are talking about the terms of the series).

Comment: @5xum When I say "its limit" I mean the limit of $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1-2+3-...+(-1)^{n-1} n}{n^2}$.  The series is $1-\frac14+\frac29-\frac2{16}+\frac3{25}-\frac3{36}+\cdots$ and it is not difficult to see whether this converges or not

Comment: In fact the series evaluates to $\frac{\pi^2}{16}+\frac12\log_e(2) \approx 0.96342$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the numerator is $\frac{n+1}2$ and $-\frac n2$ for odd and even $n$,respectively.

We have:
$$
|a_n|-|a_{n+1}|=\frac{n+1}{2n^2}-\frac{n}{2(n+1)^2}>0\tag{$n$ odd}
$$
and
$$
|a_n|-|a_{n+1}|=\frac{n}{2n^2}-\frac{n+1}{2(n+1)^2}>0.\tag{$n$ even}
$$
Thus we deal with monotone decreasing alternating series. Since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0,
$$
the series converges by [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

- $1 = 1$
- $1 - 2 = -1$
- $1 - 2 + 3 = 2$
- $1 - 2 + 3 - 4 = -2$
- $1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + 5 = 3$
- $1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + 5 - 6 = -3$

can you spot a pattern here?

Comment: Patern is easy to spot but I can't find a closed form. I can find a closed form for each even and odd n but can't find one for both

Comment: @JurgenKlop You can probably easily find a closed form for odd and even numbers, right?

Comment: Yes I can find it for even and odd numbers

Comment: @JurgenKlop Well, now try using some of the criteria!

Comment: @5xum I used limit criterion and got that series diverges but someone in the comments of my original question said that series converges

Comment: @TymaGaidash Not true, the series converges.

Comment: @JurgenKlop What is "the limit criterion", and how did you use it? I can't comment on what you did without seeing it!

Comment: For example closed form of 1-2+3-4... is $\frac{n+1}{2}$ for odd n so series is equal to $\frac{n+1}{2n^2}$. Since $\frac{n+1}{2n^2}$ behaves as $1/2×1/n$ and 1/n diverges limit criteria gives divergence of starting series.

Comment: @JurgenKlop You only proved that the sum of odd elements converges. You are forgetting the sign.

Comment: A closed closed form could be $$a_n=(-1)^{n+1}\Big\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2}\Big\rfloor$$
and for large $n$ you can asymptotically neglect the floor operation so that you can apply the Leibniz criterion

Comment: How about $\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k-1} k = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4} (-1)^n (2n+1)$.